# IIS font not applying

Tags: .net, iis, fonts, devexpress, barcode

We are experiencing an issue with IIS not picking up on a font added to the system.  Running our webservice through Visual Studio works fine and the font is used.  Here is the situation:

We have a reporting service hosted in IIS that generates DevExpress reports.  In the design of the report we have barcode numbers assigned with the appropriate font.  We install the 3of9.ttf barcode font and when run through Visual Studios Dev Server the report is generated with the barcodes displaying correctly.  Once deployed to IIS on the same machine, the report is generated with only the barcode number showing and not the barcode itself, so the font is not being used.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That's a common problem.  The 3of9 ttf barcode should be installed on every client machine.  The reporting service depends on client machine fonts for correct visualization.  Try installing the font on one client PC and browse to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well, ill try to explain with my SUPERB english:

I have a SIMILAR problem with DevXpress Richedit control and Code128 font.... I know how are you suffering :)

Same code into Windows Form app, runs ok and the PDF show the barcode, but in my WCF service, it doesnt`.
Have you seen the PDF properties? Do you have the font embbeded into it? If yes (as we have) it's more extrange indeed.

You cant try to play with NeverEmbeddedFonts property, and so on, BUT, I think that all of this:

- it's due to a iis asp pool, maybe due to a lack of privileges of the Windows account of the pool
- be sure that that fonts have been installed in the client machines
- **be sure that that fonts have been installed in the server who produces file/report, NOT using a terminal server session. Sounds crazy, but Devxpress have some issues about that.**

Good luck my friend....

---

Today, the IT-crow of our client have installed the barcode fonts "in-situ". Now it works!

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue today.
After 5 hours I found solution.
The steps I went through are:

1. Disable Any Antiviruses.
2. Install fonts for All Users on server by right clicking on font and selecting (Install for all users) option
   If you can't see the option, make sure you have logged in by administrator account.
3. Restart your system

Done.